# How to use not selector in jquery - not working

Tags: jquery, overlay

I am fixing an overlay issue here. Not sure is it possible to make it work?

The `.overlay-container` wrapper is the one with a black color background and makes the overlay center. And the `.overlay` is the real wrapper that has a white background, close button and the content inside.

What am I trying to do is when user clicks on the `.overlay-container` area, the `-active` class will be removed. But the overlay is inside of it, is it possible to say something like “not the overlay area inside”?

```js
$('.overlay-container').not('.overlay-container .overlay').click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('-active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay-container">
  <div class="overlay">something inside</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is "active" class supposed to be? On the "overlay-container" then click is supposed to remove it?

Comment: it will be in the "overlay-container" div

Comment: First, You have some quotes issue here ! I'm preparing you a fiddle

Comment: The `.not` function can be used like a filter, it filters the resulting array to exclude the matches from the `.not`.  This will not work for the nested hierarchy you have.

Comment: @nurdyguy got it. I thought it could be something simple add into. So thinking need to use the if() inside the click function

Comment: @YanMak yes using a condition inside the click function would do it! That's how I solved it in my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved [UPDATE] :
This code won't remove the class active unless you click outside the inner overlay.

```
$(".overlay-container").click(function(event) {
if( $(event.target).hasClass('overlay-container')){
    //alert("removed");
  $( this ).removeClass('active');
 }
});
```

Working here : https://jsfiddle.net/gquL65ep/

Comment: He wants the class to be removed only when the user clicks the outer `.overlay-container` but not the inner `.overlay`.  This code does not work.

Comment: @YanMak I just updated my answer after understanding the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the event from bubbling up by calling `.stopPropagation()` on the event. I have made an assumption that the active class is called `.overlay-container-active` and you are using fixed position to create the overlay background which the content sits within.

I also threw in a button to toggle the overlay so you can see it working. For the buttong I used `.on('click')` instead of `.click()`, read more about it at the [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Worth mentioning if the overlay container and content were siblings then you wouldn't have this problem; just an alternative to think about if you're interested.

```js
$('.overlay-container-active').click(function(event){
  $(this).removeClass('overlay-container-active');
});

$('.overlay').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('button').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.overlay-container').addClass('overlay-container-active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: darkorange;
}

.overlay-container {
  display: none;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay-container-active {
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show overlay</button>
<div class="overlay-container overlay-container-active">
  <div class="overlay">something inside</div>
</div>
```